# C++ modules and circular class reference

Tags: c++, c++20

To learn more about C++20 modules, I'm in the process of migrating a graphics application from header files to modules. At the moment I have a problem with a circular dependency between two classes. The two classes describe nodes and edges of a graph. The edge class has pointers to two nodes and the node class has a vector of pointers to adjacent edges. I know, there are other ways to describe a graph, but this archtitecture seems very natural to me, I have very fast access to neighboring elements and it works seamlessly in the old world of header files and #include. The key are forward references.

But in the new world of C++20 modules, forward references no longer work.

The topic of circular references has been discussed in many places, but I haven't yet found a solution that really convinces me.

A common statement is that circular references are an architectural problem and should be avoided. If necessary, the two classes should be packed into one module. That would clearly be a step backwards. I try to make modules small and elementary.

I could replace the pointers to nodes or edges with pointers to a common base class NetworkObject that actually already exists. But that would destroy valuable information and force me to use static_cast to artificially add the type information back.

My question is: Am I missing anything? Is there an easier way?

Comment: "*But in the new world of C++20 modules, forward references no longer work.*" You're going to have to provide some code to justify that statement, as nothing in modules changes the nature of how forward references work. I mean, it's possible that you had some poor `#include` usage and blindly changing bad `#include`s into `import` didn't work. But again, we can't tell without seeing some code.

Comment: Seriously modules are very young and compiler support is lacking, to be candid. There is a chance that modules, as they exist today, might be deprecated in the future as happened to many other C++ features given the lack of progress. I would not migrate a professional build to modules at this point, but that is just me.

Comment: If modules were intended to hold one class each, why do you think modules have support for exporting multiple classes?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: You are right. My statetement is a bit over-simplifying. It should be ".. no longer work in the same way as with #includes".

Comment: @Henrique Bucher: I dont't think, that modules will be depricated in the future, but I agree, that modules are very young and compiler support is not perfect yet. I would not recommend to migrate a piece of software to modules now, if the working time of the developer is taken into account. I am a hobbyist and driven by curiosity. While I was migrating my application, I learned a lot, but the time required was at least ten times as much as I originally suspected.

Comment: Things like macros cannot be exported from modules. This kills the popular Google benchmarks and Google tests right off the bat

Comment: @HenriqueBucher: ... and? Macros not being part of modules is a *feature*, not a bug. The expectation for macro libraries is that they would continue to ship headers for their macros. It's not a stopping point for anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you don't use macros you should be ok, I guess. I just pointed out that two very popular packages would have a hard time to move into modules - and they are not alone.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher: It's OK to still have header files for macros. What modules buys you is not putting *most things* in headers, and the compile-time advantages of that.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, it is not OK. If you can't fully encapsulate a library within a module, it is a failure. Nobody is going to move to modules if they are told they will have to manage manually this entire mess on a case by case basis. I'm truly skeptical of modules and its adoption at this point as an engineer who uses this technology. It is very telling that it has been years and the major compilers are still lagging support. But if you want to be everyone's guinea pig and volunteer into the trenches, whatever rocks your boat.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher: "*I'm truly skeptical of modules and its adoption at this point*" If your skepticism of modules is based on them not including macros... you were *never* on board with modules. Basically no version of any C++ modules proposal for over 10 years included exporting macros. They were off the table from day 1. Also, it's 2 of the 3 major compilers that are "still lagging support"; VS's implementation seems to be pretty good. That's not a particularly good state of affairs, but it's hardly indicative that nobody is implementing it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess time will say where adoption goes. But my hunch is that if you need modules, perhaps you should migrate to Rust or Carbon, both get it done with perfection.

Comment: It’s true that, absent the global module approach, you can’t choose (in a particular translation unit) to treat a(nother) module’s type as **incomplete** so as to avoid needing to recompile if its definition changes.  That said, generally you shouldn’t be getting new versions of an external module so frequently that this makes much of a difference (and the rebuilds should be cheaper anyway).

Answer (score 8):

There are a few misconceptions I can see here. Not entirely false, but not entirely true either.

> But in the new world of C++20 modules, forward references no longer work.

This is not completely true. You cannot use forward reference that would declare something as part of a different module, but you can certainly do that within the same module.

For example:

```
export module M;

export namespace n {
    struct B;

    struct A {
        B* b;
    };

    struct B {
        A* a;
    };
}
```

Then you can split it up in multiple module partitions:

```cpp
export module M:a;

namespace n {
    struct B;
    export struct A {
        B* b;
    };
};
```

```cpp
export module M:b;

namespace n {
    struct A;
    export struct B {
        A* b;
    };
};
```

```cpp
export module M;
export import :a;
export import :b;
```

The gist of it is that types that depends on each other to be defined are coupled enough that they must reside in the same module.

Also, note that modules are not necessarily supposed to be as granular as headers. Dividing your modules too much could hurt compile time performances. For example, a whole library could be just one big module. The standard library chose this approach and export everything in the `std` modules and turns out it's faster than dividing the standard library in many smaller modules.

Smaller modules are not as good as many may think. Related things and classes should be packed in the same module, and if further splitting is needed for code organization within that module, partitions are an option.

The amount of modules and their name is part of your API. This means that if you have too much fine grained module, simply moving your code around will result in a breaking change. Module partitions are not part of your API and can be moved around freely.

> A common statement is that circular references are an architectural problem and should be avoided. If necessary, the two classes should be packed into one module. That would clearly be a step backwards. I try to make modules small and elementary.

Those modules would not be small and elementary because of the cycle between them. ie you can't just use one module without also using the other. You will need to link against that other module if the implementation reside in another static library.

> The two classes describe nodes and edges of a graph

We there be a program that would work with only the nodes module or only the edges module? Hardly. They should be part of the `graph` module. You could have a `:edge` and `:node` partitions, but it would not make sense using only one of those in a program or part of program.

If this is for compile times, then [making bigger modules has been proven today that they are faster than smaller modules with current compiler technologies](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2412r0.pdf)

The rationale for splitting modules into smaller modules is that there would be a use case for wanting to only import certain specific things. For example, `std.freestanding` would only contain the freestanding part of the standard library so programmers don't accidentally use parts they are not allowed to use.

---

Of course, another way to do that would be to drop all the modules safeguards and use Global Module Fragments (GMF). Using that allows modules to interface with the implicit global module. And yes, using that allows the benefit and the consequences that comes with global forward declaration. You will open the way for ODR violations to become possible again, and your entities won't be part of a named module anymore. It also allows a user to use your entities without importing the specific named module the declaration reside in, bypassing the API you expose to your users via your module names.

You can open Pandora's box using the `extern "C++"` directive:

```
export module A;

export namespace n {
    extern "C++" {
        struct B;
        struct A {
            B* b;
        };
    }
}
```

```
export module B;

export namespace n {
    extern "C++" {
        struct A;
        struct B {
            A* a;
        };
    }
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ks1GePqr9)

Comment: You have two `export module M;`s; are they alternatives?

Comment: @ Guillaume Racicout: Thanks for the detailed and exhaustive answer. Exactly what I needed. It opens my eyes to the fact that I am stuck in a dogma "keep modules as small as possible". Module partitions are probably the building block I've missed so far.