# Structuring a project with circular dependencies using C++ modules

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have an existing C++ project, and although I'm being pretty experienced with C++ itself, I haven't dony anything with modules yet and I thought it was time to finally bite that bullet.

I have a small library which is currently structured in several source and header files, where each header describes a major class and some of its smaller satellite types and functions. I like this set up, and my initial take on retrofitting modules into this was simply to have each source file being a module part. But I quickly ran into the problem of circular dependencies.

For the sake of argument, let's say this is a simple JSON library that uses some variant-like type called a `JsonValue`, with a source setup like this:

```cpp
// JsonValue.h

#include "JsonArray.h"

class JsonValue
{
    std::variant<double, JsonArray> data;
    // ...
};


// JsonArray.h

class JsonValue;

class JsonArray
{
    std::vector<JsonValue> array;
    // ...
};
```

You'll notice the circular dependency here. `JsonValue` depends on the definition of `JsonArray`, and `JsonArray` depends on the *declaration* of `JsonValue`. In practice, this works fine. Although you can't construct a `JsonArray` in a translation unit that doesn't know the *definition* of `JsonValue` (the `std::vector<JsonValue>` requires this), in reality you'll never just include `JsonArray.h` without including `JsonValue.h`.

So, naive as I was, I simply converted the header files to module interface files that respectively exported the modules `json:value` and `json:array`. I `import`ed the `json:array` into `json:value`, and for `json:array` itself I didn't need to do anything else. Or so I thought.

```cpp
// JsonValue.ixx

export module json:value;
import json:array;

export class JsonValue
{
    std::variant<double, JsonArray> data;
    // ...
};


// JsonArray.ixx

export module json:array;

export class JsonArray
{
    std::vector<JsonValue> array;
    // ...
};
```

(And all member function implementations go in their respective module implementation files)

However, as it turns out, the circular dependency *is* a problem with modules, as they're essentially separate translation units with their own compilation step. The `json:array` module gets compiled separately without knowing the definition of `JsonValue`. I can't `import json:value`, because `json:value` itself is dependent on `json:array`.

**I *think* that the only solution here is to have both classes in the same module interface file.** That certainly seems the gist of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73626743/c-modules-and-circular-class-reference), although that one doesn't suffer from my problem as they just use pointers.

But I don't want that. In reality, the classes are a lot bigger than just these simple classes, and I don't want to dump them all into the same module interface file. I guess I can still hack around this using includes (which then are not supposed to be included on their own), but that feels kind of dirty. I'm really hoping there's some other solution that I'm missing.

And, perhaps naively as well, I was hoping to do away with separate class definitions and implementations by having every function implemented inline in the class itself. That certainly doesn't seem to be the case, especially not in this particular example.

Comment: As you've identified your code has a hard circular dependency. Not modules nor forward declarations or any other tricks will work around it, you have to fix your design somehow.

Comment: It's not a hard circular dependency. As far as I know you're allowed to *declare* a `std::vector<T>` with *declared* `T`. But in order to actually use it, you need `T` to be defined. Which is currently always the case. I can easily fix the problem by putting all my code in a single module interface file.

Comment: That is unfortunately not correct, a `std::vector` may not use an incomplete type ([link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/vector#overview-4)): *An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating vector if the allocator meets the allocator completeness requirements. `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of vector is referenced.*

Comment: @CoryKramer: That clearly says that, if you don't "reference" any "member of the resulting specialization", then `T` *can* be incomplete.

Comment: @oisyn: It's difficult to say exactly what you should do without seeing the actual code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @CoryKramer I think the standard allocator meets the allocator completeness requirements for incomplete T. The allocator completeness requirements themselves don't need T to be complete.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't think it would be too hard to imagine the small module interfae boilerplate around both header files, but I'll type it out.

Comment: @oisyn: It's not about "boilerplate". It's about whether there is code in, for example, `:value` that requires JsonArray to be complete, and vice-versa for `:array`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh you mean the actual function implementations inside the class definition? No they're all in the module implementation file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is make sure that the interface partition module `json:array` does not contain any code that *requires* `JsonValue` to be defined. Definitions of member functions or any other code which accesses it should not be part of that partition. They should be defined in an implementation unit, or a later interface unit, so long as they importsboth `json:array` and `json:value`.

Also, do not forget to `export` forward declarations of exported entities.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that I'm allowed to `import` the other part in both module implementation files? So I can `import json:array` in `json:value` and vice versa, *in the module implementation file* (obviously this can't be done within the module interface file)?

Comment: @oisyn: You can import interface units in implementation units, yes. Indeed, non-partition interface units implicitly import the primary module interface for that module. Interface units can import other interface units, so long as the resulting graph is acyclic. That is, the `#include` in your example just becomes an `export import` of that interface partition unit.

Comment: It works! I knew you could import modules in module implementation units, but I didn't realize you could import them "circularly". But it's an implementation after all, as long as the interface isn't circular. Awesome!

Comment: Wait, one question. You say "don't forget to `export` forward declarations". Is this mandatory in module partitions as well? I thought they automatically shared everything.

Comment: @oisyn: You can't have circular imports of any kind. It's just that module implementation units don't get imported (unless they're partitions). They're not part of the interface, so they're not included by the interface.

Comment: Right, now that you put it like that it's so obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @oisyn: "*Is this mandatory in module parts as well?*" Well, kinda. If a declaration that is not exported is later seen as exported, you get a compile error. But a declaration that was exported is later seen as non-exported, that's fine (it's still exported). The problem is how "later" works, which is well-defined, but can be confusing. So I would say to just be consistent with them unless they are in the same file.